# Preparing an amine from an azide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, amines

Is there any mechanism available for reduction of alkyl azides to amines.
One of the reactions is conversion by $\ce{Na}$ in ethanol or by $\ce{LiAlH4}$.
But how do these proceed?
$\ce{LiAlH4}$ will produce a hydride ion which attacks where?

Comment: Different reagents will have different mechanisms. Are you interested in one reagent in particular?

Comment: the ones I have mentioned i.e. Na in ethanol and LAH

Answer (score -1):

I googled it for a while and this was the best thing I found ([Source](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100525170905AA9PDiD)):

> This is a tough question, that is probably not known with any certainty.
>   Even Jerry March (Adv Organic Chem, 4th ed, page 1219) doesn't commit himself to a mechanism.
>
> You'll have to speculate.   Add a hydride on the N next to the alkyl group, then
>   grab a proton on the terminal N.    Add a hydride on the terminal N, then grab a proton on the middle N.  After that, it gets a little sketchy for breaking the N-N bond.
>
> Try a SN2 attack by hydride on the middle N, giving hydrazine and  RNH-, which is a lousy SN2 leaving group, but we're stuck with it.
>   Protonation of the RNH- gives the amine and hydrazine.   Or, you could do a SN2 on the N next to the alkyl group, and kick out a NH2NH- anion, which is also a lousy leaving group for the SN2.
>   You can see why most books conveniently leave out a mechanism for this reduction.

Comment: I don't see the mechanism on that link. Which page are you referring to exactly?

Comment: At the current state, this doesn't provide an answer to the question. Am flagging for deletion.

Comment: This is a better one, but it's highly encouraged (read: required) that you put the link to the source here.

Comment: I'm finding https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100525170905AA9PDiD as a source

Comment: If you are quoting verbatim, **always** mention the source. I will insert it for now since @austinian already found it, but please avoid that in future answers.

Comment: @austinian thanks for putting the link; I generally put it, but in this case, I don't know how I forgot...

Comment: @Martin-マーチン as I said, I don't do it, but I forgot in this case; maybe because I previously provided not so correct answer,  then edited later. Anyways, thanks for reminding.